# Inaccessible conversion in QObject

Tags: c++, qt

Here is my sample code:

```
class hoho : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    hoho() 
    {
        httpFetch = new HttpFetch(QUrl("http://www.google.com/"));
        connect(httpFetch, SIGNAL(Fetched()), this, SLOT(PrintData(QByteArray)));
    }

    void PrintData(QByteArray http)
    {
        qDebug()<<http;
    }

    HttpFetch *httpFetch;
};
```

When I try to compile this, following error pops up

```
1>main.cpp(15): error C2243: 'type cast' : conversion from 'HttpFetch *' to 'const QObject *' exists, but is inaccessible
```

This error comes as the class is derived from `QObject` (which is necessary for signal and slot mechanism).

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Your constructor is not correct, at least, because you connect a local object `httpFetch` (that will be destroyed at the end of the ctor scope) to `this`. I'm not sure but it could be the origin of this error message. If not, well, you'll still have a problem and no connection as soon as the execution exits the ctor scope. It seems you should rather initialize your member variable... Right now, the local `httpFetch` hides the member variable `httpFetch`.

Comment: I tried it as you said. But error remains same.

Comment: Well, currently, the ctor code is wrong. Best case, there won't be a connexion once the ctor ends, worst case you have UB because the pointer the connexion is holding for the signal is garbage.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You probably did not derive `HttpFetch` publicly, but privately from `QObject`. So just change

```
class HttpFetch : QObject { // ...
```

to

```
class HttpFetch : public QObject { // ...
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 5):

If your design requires to make the inheritance non-public (I had this requirement because I inherited from a `QWidget` for a multithreading purpose and didn't want to expose all functions to the user), you can do this:

```
class FilesQueueQList : protected QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    using QWidget::QObject; //This is the solution!
//...
}
```

Now the members of QWidget are private/protected, but QObject is accessible as public.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget the Q_OBJECT macro in your class HttpFetch ?

Can I see your class HttpFetch ?

Comment: Q_OBJECT macro was there, but the QObject was privately derived. Now the problem in fixed.